# vim - how to bind the screen scroll down command

Tags: vim

I try to press `ctrl-d` to scroll half-page down. However, it springs a nerdtree table. Now I try to map `ctrl-d` to the origin command, after trying `:scroll`, `:startofline`... I can't figure out how to bind the origin command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:unmap <C-d>` to remove the mapping.

Use `:verbose map <C-d>` to see what it's mapped to and where it was last mapped.